# docker-compose not serving Nuxt.js website under localhost:3000

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

While I know that the course was meant for backend apps, I've tried making a docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile for a frontend Nuxt.js app.
My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Any my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.0-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

COPY package.json yarn.lock* ./

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps alpine-sdk python \
 && yarn && yarn cache clean \
 && apk del .build-deps

ENV PATH=./node_modules/.bin/:$PATH

COPY . .

CMD ["nuxt"]
```

When I run this with `docker-compose up`, my application builds and starts properly though the `nuxt` CMD, but when I go to http://localhost:3000 the app isn't online.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The two usual causes are a dev server defaulting to serving on the container-private `localhost` interface (set it to run on 0.0.0.0), or using Docker Toolbox (use the `docker-machine ip` address, usually 192.168.99.100).  Remember that your `volumes:` declaration actively prevents Docker from ever updating your `node_modules` tree, which you probably don’t want.

Comment: what shows the command docker-compose logs web ?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm on Windows 10 Pro, so I use normal Docker Desktop instead of Docker Toolbox, so that one is cleared. How do I make the container serve to `0.0.0.0` instead of internal localhost? I bet that's the cause? To update my dependencies I use `docker-compose run web yarn`

Comment: @DavidMaze The `0.0.0.0` advice was correct! I added `ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0` to my Dockerfile and it works now. Maybe post your advice as an answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 1):

your cmd should be

```
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

in docker compose you can add the line command and use it for apply dev or start when you need.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: yarn dev 
    # or
    # command: yarn build && yarn start
```